# Composition of convex and $L^1$ function is not $L^1$ function.

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of functions $f\in L^1$ and $\varphi$ is convex such that $\varphi\circ f\notin L^1$ but $$\varphi \left(\int \limits_{X}f d\mu\right)\leq \int\limits_{X} \varphi \circ f d\mu.$$ I suspect that $f$ should be some function which blows up and $\varphi$ some power of its. But I am not able to make it rigorous. Can anyone help with this example, please.

Answer (score 0):

How about $X = [0,1]$, $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, $f(x) = \dfrac 1{\sqrt x}$, and $\phi(x) = x^2$.